# JAX-WS how to return custom class object from 3rd party library

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I am writing a JAX-WS web services that should return custom object that is a party of 3rd party library.

The example of method is:

```
@WebMethod
public CustomObject create(CustomObject2 object)
```

I am not able to modify `CustomObject` as it is part of 3rd party library.
Is there any simple way how to change this to have JAX-B-compatible parameters and return types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `CustomObject` is a POJO, you can use inheritance to add the JAXB annotations, and apache commons [BeanUtils.copyProperties](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) to clone the properties to the JAXB object

**CustomObjectJAXB**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CustomObject")
public class CustomObjectJAXB extends CustomObject{
```

**WebMethod**

```
@WebMethod
public CustomObject create(CustomObject2 object)
   CustomObject co = ... // Get CustomObject from third party library

   CustomObjectJAXB coJaxb = new CustomObjectJAXB()
   BeanUtils.copyProperties (coJaxb,co);
   return coJaxb;
}
```

This solutions is simply and probably works fine with plain objects, but if CustomObject is complex (contains lists, maps, or other objects), the resultant xml probably won't be very orthodox